# Hive failed to create /user/hive/warehouse

Tags: hadoop, hive

I just get started on Apache Hive, and I am using my local Ubuntu box 12.04, with Hive 0.10.0 and Hadoop 1.1.2.

Following the official "[Getting Started](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted)" guide on Apache website, I am now stuck at the Hadoop command to create the hive metastore with the command in the guide:

```
$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -mkdir       /user/hive/warehouse
```

the error was `mkdir: failed to create /user/hive/warehouse`

Does Hive require hadoop in a specific mode? I know I didn't have to do much to my Hadoop installation other that update JAVA_HOME so it is in standalone mode. I am sure Hadoop itself is working since I am run the PI example that comes with hadoop installation.

Also, the other command to create `/tmp` shows the `/tmp` directory already exists so it didn't recreate, and `/bin/hadoop fs -ls` is listing the current directory.

So, how can I get around it?

Answer (score 22):

Almost all examples of the documentation have this command wrong.  Just like unix you will need the "-p" flag to create the parent directories as well unless you have already created them.  This command will work.

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -mkdir -p    /user/hive/warehouse
```

Answer (score 6):

When running hive on local system, just add to ~/.hiverc:

```
SET hive.metastore.warehouse.dir=${env:HOME}/Documents/hive-warehouse;
```

You can specify any folder to use as a warehouse. Obviously, any other [hive configuration](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+Configuration) method will do (hive-site.xml or hive -hiveconf, for example).

That's possibly what **Ambarish Hazarnis** kept in mind when saying "or Create the warehouse in your home directory".

Comment: Mine had to created inside `/usr/local/Cellar/hive/2.3.1/libexec/conf` on MacOS (using HomeBrew as the package manager)

Comment: this does not work at all with hive 3.1.3, -1

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a permission issue. Do you have access to root folder / ?
Try the following options-

```
1. Run command as superuser

OR

2.Create the warehouse in your home directory.
```

Let us know if this helps. Good luck!

Comment: yes it turns out to be a simple permission issue, so "sudo bin/hadoop fs -mkdir       /user/hive/warehouse" did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When setting hadoop properties in the spark configuration, prefix them with `spark.hadoop`.

Therefore set

```
conf.set("spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.warehouse.dir","/new/location")
```

This works for older versions of Spark. The  property has changed in spark 2.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Adding answer for ref to Cloudera CDH users who are seeing this same issue.

If you are using Cloudera CDH distribution, make sure you have followed these steps:

- launched Cloudera Manager (Express / Enterprise) by clicking on the desktop icon.
- Open Cloudera Manager page in browser
- Start all services

Cloudera has /user/hive/warehouse folder created by default. Its just that YARN and HDFS might not be up and running to access this path.

Answer (score 0):

While this is a simple permission issue that was resolved with sudo in my comment above, there are a couple of notes:

1. create it in home directory should work as well, but then you may need to update hive setting for the path of metastore, which I think defaults to /user/hive/warehouse
2. I ran into another error of CREATE TABLE statement with Hive shell, the error was something like this:

hive> CREATE TABLE pokes (foo INT, bar STRING);
FAILED: Error in metadata: MetaException(message:Got exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException File file:/user/hive/warehouse/pokes does not exist.)
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask

It turns to be another permission issue, you have to create a group called "hive" and then add the current user to that group and change ownership of /user/hive/warehouse to that group. After that, it works. Details can be found from this link below:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hive-user/201104.mbox/%3CBANLkTinq4XWjEawu6zGeyZPfDurQf+j8Bw@mail.gmail.com%3E

Answer (score 0):

if you r running linux check (in hadoop core-site.xml )  data directory & permission, it looks like you ve kept the default which is /data/tmp and im most cases that will take root permission .. 
change the xml config file , delete /data/tmp and run fs format (OC after you ve modified the core xml config)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using upper versions of hive i.e. 1.1.0 version, 0.10.0 is very buggy.

Answer (score 0):

- Run this command and try to create a directory it would grant full permission for the user in hdfs /user directory.
  **hadoop fs -chmod -R 755 /user**

Answer (score 0):

I am using MacOS and homebrew as package manager. I had to set the property in hive-site.xml as

```
<property>
    <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
    <value>/usr/local/Cellar/hive/2.3.1/libexec/conf/warehouse</value>
</property>
```